# Push notification impact by account migration from individual to company

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am transferring my account from individual to company. While this process is on-going, my apps are currently still operating. I wanted to know whether it would impact the push notification functionality of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am providing my feedback here as I think it might help others.

iOS push notification would be impacted when the you are migrating your Apple Developer account from single to company type.

From my own experience, this would takes around 5-6 days before the Push Notification able to start working again.

I was doing a lot of debugging (from thinking it might be due to cert has expired, getting new versions updated for server based push notification, etc) only to find out that the Push Notification just automatically start working after 5-6 days later.